# Problem scrolling the page to the top when clicking on Dropdown(ngSelect)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

There are 3 ngselect dropdown structures on the page. There is no problem with the areas on the left side of the page. This problem occurs when an element moves a certain amount to the right on the page.

I want to open only the menu when I click and prevent the page from scrolling to the top. This is the first time I encounter such an error. I would be grateful if you could help.

###### Status

```
          <div class="status-dropdown">
            <ng-select [dropdownPosition]="'top'"
              [searchable]="false"
              [clearable]="false"
              [items]="statusItems"
              bindLabel="display"
              bindValue="value"
              [(ngModel)]="packageDetail.status"
              (change)="updateKeyResultStatus(packageDetail, objective, packageDetail.status)">
            </ng-select>          
          </div>
```